# spring-data-rest: Validator not being invoked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using springboot 2.0.1.RELEASE with spring-data-rest and followed the workaround mentioned here and my Validator is still not being invoked. Here are the details:

ValidatorRegistrar: [Workaround for a bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-524?focusedCommentId=117547&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-117547)

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorRegistrar implements InitializingBean {

    private static final List<String> EVENTS;
    static {
        List<String> events = new ArrayList<String>();
        events.add("beforeCreate");
        events.add("afterCreate");
        events.add("beforeSave");
        events.add("afterSave");
        events.add("beforeLinkSave");
        events.add("afterLinkSave");
        events.add("beforeDelete");
        events.add("afterDelete");
        EVENTS = Collections.unmodifiableList(events);
    }

    @Autowired
    ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingRepositoryEventListener;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Validator> validators = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(Validator.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Validator> entry : validators.entrySet()) {
            EVENTS.stream().filter(p -> entry.getKey().startsWith(p)).findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(p -> validatingRepositoryEventListener.addValidator(p, entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

Validator class:

```
@Component("beforeSaveBidValidator")
public class BeforeSaveBidValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Bid.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        Bid bid = (Bid)target;
        if (!bid.getAddendaAcknowledged()) {
            errors.rejectValue("addendaAcknowledged", 
                "addendaAcknowledged is not true");
        }
    }
}
```

Custom RestController for Bids:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/bids")
public class BidController {

    private BidRepository bidRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BidController(
        BidRepository bidRepository) {
        this.bidRepository = bidRepository;
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public Bid update(@RequestBody @Valid Bid bid) {
        return bidRepository.save(bid);
    }
}
```

Rest Client Test Code:

```
Bid bid = new Bid()
...
bid.setAddendaAcknowledged(false)

Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<String, String>()
uriVariables.put("id", bid.id)

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
HttpEntity<Bid> entity = new HttpEntity<>(bid, headers)
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        "/bids/{id}", HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Bid.class, bid.id)

// Expected: response.statusCode == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
// Found: response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
// Debugger showed that Validator was never invoked.
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use your validator with custom controller, not SDR controller. In this case you can just add it to your controller with `@InitBinder` annotation:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bids")
public class BidController {

    //...

    @InitBinder("bid") // add this parameter to apply this binder only to request parameters with this name
    protected void bidValidator(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new BidValidator());
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Bid update(@RequestBody @Valid Bid bid) {
        return bidRepository.save(bid);
    }
}
```

`@Component` annotation on your validator is not necessary as well as `ValidatorRegistrar` class.

---

How to use validators with SDR controllers you can read in my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114221/5380322).

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi You're welcome! Please don't forget to accept the answer... )